# Efficiently store base64 image output of chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How to efficiently store base64 screen capture from chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() API to disk. I know we can use chrome.storage.local to store base64 but is it efficient. Is there any way to store on disk and access it using a URL

Comment: You can store the image in [HTML5 File System](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem//) which is available only in Chrome and use direct URLs without encoding to base64 (you'll use `toURL` as shown in the article).

Comment: since HTML5 file system is Deprecated the only option is to use chrome.storage.local

Comment: Use IndexedDB, which is much faster, and store the image as a decoded ArrayBuffer. Then you can read it, make a new `Blob`, then make a URL using URL.createObjectURL.